# sorting of json data by jQuery.parseJSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, sorting

I receive following json object:

```
{
  "ActivitySummary": [
    {
      "Client": "TOTAL",
      "RGUs": "18",
      "CANCELLED": "1",
      "PENDING": "17"
    },
    {
      "Client": "ATT",
      "RGUs": "2",
      "CANCELLED": "1",
      "PENDING": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I parse this object using `jQuery.parseJSON()` it changes the order of properties i.e `Client` moves on second place, 'CANCELLED' to the first and so on:

```
var array=[
             {CANCELLED:"1",Client:"TOTAL", RGUs:"18", PENDING:"1" },
             {CANCELLED:"1",Client:"ATT", RGUs:"2", PENDING:"1"}
          ];
```

This is how I parse json:

```
success: function (obj) {
    var array = jQuery.parseJSON(obj.data);
}
```

How can I retain the order? Please help

Comment: why do you want to keep the order?

Comment: You don't need to call `jQuery.parseJSON()`. jQuery does that automatically when you send the data with content type `application/json`, as you should do anyway. The question about key order in Javascript has been asked so many times already, you could have found that yourself.

Comment: The order od properties has no importance in a JSON object

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh because I want to insert the data dynamically in an HTML table. Order matters

Comment: @Tomalak I'm calling `jQuery.parseJSON()` because I want data in tree notation.

Comment: That statement does not make sense. Read my comment again.

Comment: @Tomalak yes got it. You are right. Thanks

Comment: why do not you use JSON.parse ? Just tried in chrome and it preserves the order